# How to find the sum of all numbers in an array?

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift, sum

I have a class of UITableViewController:

```
class foodListTable: UITableViewController
```

I have an array with 9 number values in it:

```
var calorieNumberArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

(Yes, the values in the array do change.) I am trying to find the sum of all the values in the array. I have tried by creating this constant:

```
let calorieTotal = calorieNumberArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
```

I used the apple developer page to figure this out at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array. Whenever I use `let calorieTotal = array.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }`, I get an error: "'foodListTable.Type' does not have a member named 'calorieNumberArray'"

How can I fix this? Do I need to change the way I'm adding the numbers in the array?

Here is all of my code for this class:

```
class foodListTable: UITableViewController {
var calorieNumberArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
let calorieTotal = calorieNumberArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
var foods = [Food]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.foods = [Food(Name: "Small French Fries: 197 Cal."),Food(Name: "Cheeseburger: 359 Cal., One Patty"),Food(Name: "Cheese Pizza: 351 Cal., One Slice"),Food(Name: "Fried Chicken Breast: 320 Cal."),Food(Name: "Large Taco: 571 Cal."),Food(Name: "Hotdog: 315 Cal., With Ketchup"),Food(Name: "Tuna Sandwich: 287 Cal."),Food(Name: "1 Cup Vanilla Ice Cream: 290 Cal."),Food(Name: "1 1/2 Cup Vegetable Salad: 30 Cal.")]
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.foods.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    var food : Food
    food = foods[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel.text = food.Name
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    return cell
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if cell.accessoryType == .None {

            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                calorieNumberArray[0] = 197
            }
            if indexPath.row == 1 {
                calorieNumberArray[1] = 359
            }
            if indexPath.row == 2 {
                calorieNumberArray[2] = 351
            }
            if indexPath.row == 3 {
                calorieNumberArray[3] = 320
            }
            if indexPath.row == 4 {
                calorieNumberArray[4] = 571
            }
            if indexPath.row == 5 {
                calorieNumberArray[5] = 315
            }
            if indexPath.row == 6 {
                calorieNumberArray[6] = 287
            }
            if indexPath.row == 7 {
                calorieNumberArray[7] = 290
            }
            if indexPath.row == 8 {
                calorieNumberArray[8] = 30
            }

            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {

            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                calorieNumberArray[0] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 1 {
                calorieNumberArray[1] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 2 {
                calorieNumberArray[2] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 3 {
                calorieNumberArray[3] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 4 {
                calorieNumberArray[4] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 5 {
                calorieNumberArray[5] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 6 {
                calorieNumberArray[6] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 7 {
                calorieNumberArray[7] = 0
            }
            if indexPath.row == 8 {
                calorieNumberArray[8] = 0
            }

            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: type names should be capitalized: `FoodListTable`, not `foodListTable`.

Comment: Ok, I will fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you'd want to have that sum as a *computed property*, so that it will give you the current sum, and not a value that is only calculated once. To do that, replace the `calorieTotal` declaration with:

```
var calorieTotal: Int { 
    return calorieNumberArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
}
```

The problem with your current code is that properties of a class can't access other properties in their declarations.

Comment: If you prefer you can use @handiansom sugestion and reduce it to `calorieNumberArray.reduce(0, +)` :)

Answer (score 0):

1)Ensure that array has elements to iterate over them
2)Construct looping with array length as condition and with in loop
a)Iterate each and every element in an array using the index
b)Add one after the other value present in array in an primitive type variable ie.,total

Comment: I am sorry, but I am very new to programming. I added the entire class. I was wondering if you could provide the code I need to add/change since now I added the class. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Swift 3.
> ```
>
> let sum = calorieNumberArray.reduce(0, +)